# Injecting ApplicationContext into Wicket Component with @SpringBean fails

Tags: java, spring, wicket, applicationcontext

I have a Spring Project with Wicket. I can successfully inject Services in Wicket components with @SpringBean annotation.

Now, I want to access the Spring Application Context. So I've declared a member variable of type ApplicationContext and annotated it with @SpringBean, just like other services as well:

trying to use @SpringBean to inject the Application

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {

    @SpringBean
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    ...
}
```

However, at runtime, this gives the error

```
bean of type [org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext] not found
```

Is it not possible to inject ApplicationContext into Wicket Components? If so, what would be a suitable way to get access to the ApplicationContext?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ApplicationContext should be accessible in your application class.

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

Create a getApplicationContext method in your application class.

```
public class MyApplication extends WebApplication {

    public ApplicationContext getAppCtx() {
        return WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    }

}
```

The application object can be accessed from any wicket component.

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {

    public MyPanel(String id) {
        ...
        ApplicationContext appCtx = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getAppCtx();
        ...
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ApplicationContext can't be injected as a bean, as it is not in fact a bean.

Spring provides the [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) interface to provide your application with an easy way to get to spring context:

```
public class MyContentProvider extends Panel implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
         applicationContext=ctx;
    }

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

The Spring engine, at instantiate the bean, will detect the interface and access the setter.

At your wicket component, inject this provider:

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {

    @SpringBean
    private MyContentProvider contextProvider;

    ...
}
```

And use it:

```
contextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("foo");
```

Comment: Why not implement the ApplicationContextAware interface directly in the MyPanel component? Would reduce the level of complexity ;) BTW - good answer! Didn't know until today about the existence of this interface.

Comment: @magomi True, it would reduce complexity, but I don't know the wicket framework, and don't know if its components are initialized via Spring engine, or it uses its own engine (which could make this wouldn't work). This solution is complex, but I'm pretty sure it will work :)